# A plane graph problem

Tags: graph-theory

Let G be a planar graph, with edges colored red and blue. Show that there is a vertex v such that going round the vertex in a clockwise direction we encountered no more than two change of colors.

Has anybody any idea about this question?

Comment: It is a classical lemma. But it looks like homework. Better ask it elsewhere, for example, on MSE.

Comment: It was already asked on MSE, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/541651/a-bicolored-plane-graph-contains-a-vertex-with-low-oscillation, and it's exercise 1.73 in Modern Graph Theory by Bollobás.

Answer (score 2):

This is Cauchy's Combinatorial Lemma, which is Lemma 26.8 in [Pak's book.](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~pak/geompol8.pdf)